# What is alternate to the mysql cursor?

Tags: mysql, sql, shell, stored-procedures, scripting

As per my knowledge the only use of cursor is to pick values one by one from a stack for each **fetch**

In shell script same can be achieved using FOR or WHILE loop.

Example:

```
while read ip; 
do 
echo $ip
done < ./test.txt
```

(OR)

```
  IFS=$'\n'
   for ip in $(cat ./test.txt)
     do
       echo "$ip"
    done
```

**Here if test.txt has multiple lines then for one iteration one line will be loaded to varible** ip .

How to achieve same in mysql procedure without cursor and with using FOR (or) WHILE loop.

Below is example of procedure in which cursor used. I want to apply solution in below procedure only.

```
   delimiter $$
     create procedure Replace_URL_IP()
    begin
    declare finished varchar(20);
    declare ip varchar(20);
    declare c1 cursor for select SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(VALUE,'/',3),'//',-1),':',1) IP from rbt_parameters where PARAM like '%URL%' and VALUE like 'http%';
   declare continue handler for NOT FOUND set finished=1;
   open c1;
   start_loop: loop
       fetch c1 into ip;
              update rbt_parameters set value=replace(value,ip,'127.0.0.1') where PARAM like '%URL%' and VALUE like 'http%';
              if finished=1 then
              leave start_loop;
              end if;
              end loop;
  close c1;
  end
  $$
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no for/while loop structure in MySQL stored procedures to iterate over a query result. You show an example using a cursor, which is the only way. There have been requests for a simpler syntax (for example https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68758) but so far none has been implemented for MySQL.

Perhaps you would find it more productive to write code in an application programming language, not a MySQL stored procedure. To be honest, I dislike MySQL stored procedures, and I don't use them.

In the example you show, one alternative you can use in a stored procedure is to use an UPDATE statement to apply the change to all rows in a matching set:

```
UPDATE rbt_parameters
SET VALUE = REPLACE(VALUE,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, '/', 3),
      '//', -1),
    ':', 1),
  '127.0.0.1')
WHERE PARAM LIKE '%URL%' AND VALUE LIKE 'http%';
```

Comment: Hi thanks for that, but if i have to achieve same with for/while loop without using cursor, what is the syntax ?           in same the way its feasible in above mentioned shell script syntax.